# Why do these Swift static variables have empty getters?

Tags: swift

I took a look at the auto-generated Swift header for the Objective-C option enum `NSLayoutFormatOptions`:

```
struct NSLayoutFormatOptions : RawOptionSetType {
    init(_ rawValue: UInt)
    init(rawValue: UInt)

    static var AlignAllLeft: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get }
    static var AlignAllRight: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get }
    static var AlignAllTop: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get }
    static var AlignAllBottom: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get }
    static var AlignAllLeading: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get }
    static var AlignAllTrailing: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get }
    static var AlignAllCenterX: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get }
    static var AlignAllCenterY: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get }
    static var AlignAllBaseline: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get }
    static var AlignAllLastBaseline: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get }
    static var AlignAllFirstBaseline: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get }

    static var AlignmentMask: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get }

    /* choose only one of these three
     */
    static var DirectionLeadingToTrailing: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get } // default
    static var DirectionLeftToRight: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get }
    static var DirectionRightToLeft: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get }

    static var DirectionMask: NSLayoutFormatOptions { get }
}
```

The syntax on the lines declaring the static variables is confusing to me. It looks like protocol syntax, requiring getters for each of these variables, but this is a `struct` declaration. What's going on here?

I've also now noticed this on another struct, `CGSize`:

```
struct CGSize {
    var width: CGFloat
    var height: CGFloat
}

extension CGSize {
    static var zeroSize: CGSize { get }
    init()
    init(width: Int, height: Int)
    init(width: Double, height: Double)
}
```

Again, this happens only on a `static var`.

Comment: I think it's just a poor translation of an enum with const values.  You can't always trust the Obj-C to Swift rendering in Xcode, even if the interop works.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSLayoutFormatOptions

Comment: @chrisco Hmm. Put another way: if I were to write my own struct in a native `.swift` file, and use this syntax for one of its `static var` members, what would that indicate? Would it even work?

Comment: It doesn't compile, for as you say it looks like a protocol.  It's trying to be an enum though, which is how you use it.  It's a bug, but a benign one - when compared to all the others still lurking.